# Why is zero inserted as the root node here?

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

In main, I create the tree:
    TreeNode * bst = malloc (sizeof (TreeNode));

Then pass it in to the tree creation function, along with a list of int values to be entered;

```
void thisFunc(TreeNode** root, const int * elements[], const int count){

  const int * test = *elements;
  TreeNode * temp;

  for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
    temp = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = test[i];
    sort(root, temp);
  }
}
```

The nodes are created without error, as far as I can tell, and I suspect the issue is in my insertion function:

```
void sort(TreeNode** root, TreeNode * temp) {

    // are we putting our node in here?
    if (!(*root)){
     *root = temp;
     printf("ROOT: %i \n", (*root)->data);
     return;
    }
    if (temp->data <= (*root)->data) {
      sort(&(*root)->left, temp);
    }
    else if (temp->data > (*root)->data) {
      sort(&(*root)->right, temp);
    }
}
```

I tried printing out the data value to see if it was assigning 0 initially, but it doesn't seem to be.

Can anyone see what's wrong with this tree creation?

Comment: c doesn't assign default value to variable is that what you are talking about

Comment: No, it's not.  Instead of the first node being inserted into the tree, a node with the value "zero" is being put in first and the other nodes are being entered after.  I can't tell where the zero-data initial node is coming from.

Comment: `TreeNode * bst = malloc (sizeof (TreeNode));`  --> `TreeNode * bst = NULL;`

Comment: Can you show the output or explain what "zero is inserted as the root node" means here? (do you mean that the root nodes' data is 0? what are the numbers that you used? What is the output? What is the printing algorithm?)

Comment: That did the trick, BLUEPIXY.  Thanks! Can you explain why malloc was inserting the node, by any chance? 

The root node's data was 0, regardless of input.

Comment: @Rohawk It's not `sort` that inserts the extra node, it's you. By the time the first node is ready to be inserted, your `bst` already has one node in it, with uninitialized data that happens to be zero. You add this node yourself at the top of your program, as BLUEPIXY sais.